# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' \ Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

In class Detail_Window() i am assining a value a to be the class Book_Window then i am using b and c to be the value of from_user and to_user i am getting an error like this :

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Please help me with this

This is the code

In .py file

```
class Book_Window(Screen):
    from_user = ObjectProperty(None)
    to_user = ObjectProperty(None)


class Detail_Window(Screen):
    a = Book_Window()
    b = a.from_user.text
    c = a.to_user.text

    def check(self, value):
        if value == True and self.b == "Chennai" and self.c == "Sivakasi":
            checkcheck = "Amount : 400"
            print(checkcheck)
        else:
            checkcheck = "Amount : 600"
            print(checkcheck)
```

In .kv file

```
<Book_Window>:
    from_user: from_user
    to_user: to_user

<Detail_Window>:

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Amount : 400" if root.b == "Chennai" and root.c == "Sivakasi" else "Amount : 600"
            font_size: 30
```

Comment: What is ObjectProperty?. I think your code is incomplete

Comment: @SauravRai I have updated

Answer (score 0):

it is because in `Book_Window` class the `from_user` and `to_user` are `None`,

so `None` (that is NoneType) doesn't have text value

**Edit**

to define them you can do:

```
class Book_Window(Screen, form_user, to_user):
    self.from_user = from_user
    self.to_user = to_user

a = Book_Window('the values you want to assign them')
```

Comment: Then how can i do it ??